# Transparent toolbar with drawer layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

Currently, I have a transparent toolbar with drawerlayout. It is positioned in a framelayout so the drawerlayout is overlapped by the toolbar but I want it to be underneath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/tb_background"
        app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</FrameLayout>
```

How can I make it so transparent toolbar does not overlap drawerlayout?

Comment: add screenshot please?

Comment: I want to make it so the toolbar does not overlap the drawerlayout

Answer (score 0):

very first of all you don't need extra frame layout for your drawer layout. Just match your layout as shown below.

> Instead using list view you can use new support navigation view for
>   navigation menu as it saves you from extra coding and gives your app an
>   standard looks like other android application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- this is the main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/tb_background"
        app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- you used here listView -->
    <!-- this is the navigation -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

follow the official documentation below:

[Creating Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

[NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the `DrawerLayout` as root layout and inside it use the `FrameLayout` with `Toolbar`.

Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/tb_background"
        app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```